# Facebook unity sdk logs in to FB fine with Galaxy S3 but not on another S3:

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, galaxy, facebook-unity-sdk

Testing a game using the FB sdk for unity for android.  FB login is good on one S3 but doesn't work on another????

How can this happen?

Comment: What version of the unity sdk are you using?  Also, do you have the facebook app installed on either of the phones?  If so what version is the facebook app?

Comment: The latest version of the FB SDK.  Yes the FB app is installed on both devices.  I made them uninstall and reinstall the fb app so it is up to date.   I am having the one that doesn't work uninstall the app now to test it.

Comment: Tester that could not login to FB via the android game on the S3, uninstalled the FB app and it worked.  Is there a way to fix this??  I am waiting to see if it works if he reinstalls the FB app.

Comment: Upon uninstalling the FB app then ingame logging into FB was successful, then reinstalled FB app and login through game is successful..I need to know how to fix this.

Comment: Jason: do you know how to get the phone back into this state? We're trying to figure out a repro, one observation is that it seems to happen on phones that are used for testing, e.g. when switching users a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Aaron,  Not sure once it is uninstalled and logged in through the game it works fine.  This was a tester but not a test phone.  But it is with "unknown sources allowed" checked in the phones dev settings.   Also, Another phone only worked with "publish_actions" permissions being granted.

Comment: @Aaron, maybe setting the phone back to factory defaults would recreate it...not sure.  I need this resolved though....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066822/facebook-sdk-for-unity-android-does-not-log-in-if-facebook-app-is-installed/22088519?noredirect=1#comment33670349_22088519

Check this out.