# Facebook SDK for Unity Android does not log in if Facebook App is installed

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

[Related post #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051361/facebook-unity-sdk-on-android-login-fails-when-fb-app-installed)

[Related post #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894006/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-gives-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id-while-lo)

So my problem is the same as the one in these posts, but I have no idea how to implement any of the solutions found in the threads. I'm running FB SDK 4.3.6 with Unity 4.2.0. I'm basically just trying to run the InteractiveConsole Scene with an android phone that has the FB app installed. When trying to login it just throws me back to the console. Without the FB app the login works perfectly.

Now I do know that those solutions work somehow, but where or how in the world should I use them? None of the answers really tell that in a way that an idiot like me could understand. I don't have any experience on Java or Android in itself, so all I can do is Unity and C#. So how would I modify the InteractiveConsole script to make this work?

Comment: are you used "facebook.isSessionValid()" method...? It shows user is already present or not.It returns simply true or false.

Comment: There is no such method available.

Comment: just go through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this fixed by printing the keyHash from AndroidFacebook.OnLoginComplete() to a GUIText and the copying it from there to the facebook dev site. All other means gave me an invalid hash. I have no idea why this is the case, but I'm just glad it works.

Comment: There are roughly 10 billion ways your key hash can be wrong.  Your version of openssl can be broken or misconfigured. Or, if you have submitted to the kindle store, your app will be re-signed by amazon.  We added the keyhash to the login response to work around this.  The one we return with the callback is guaranteed to be correct.